# Problems with Materials on imported mantaflow object

Tags: shaders, mantaflow

When I import a baked mesh object using the mantaflow simulation, and applying a material to it, it doesn't appear to hold the same "material properties" as any other object imported or created in blender. It seems like the object doesn't let light pass through it normally. All materials appear to be much darker.

Applying a glass shader to the object is ecxeptionally noticeable.
The object on the left is the simulation, the one to the right is the imported object.
They both have the exact same shader applied. Can anyone help me in fixing this issue?
Or help me understand why it does this?

[image]

This is the imported mesh:
[image]

This is the material both objects share (basic glass shader, nothing changed):
[image]
[image]

Comment: First of all, a screenshot of the material would be helpful as well - and apart from that it's hard to tell from just seeing two objects next to each other. At first glance it simply looks like they are using materials. If you say they are the same, then the question is how the meshes of the two objects differ from each other. Hard to tell in this view either. What is all this glittering? Is the object full of bubbles or other particles?

Comment: Well the actual simulation does'nt have much of a mesh until it is baked. it is just a cube when you enter edit mode (The object to the left). The object to the right, however, is the baked mesh imported back into blender. I Had to re-bake the simulation so its a bit different but ill post a pic of the imported objects mesh and the shader both are using.

Comment: Sooo... is it full of bubbles? Maybe the _Max Bounce_ settings under _Light Paths_ are not high enough. I guess your simulation results in a very dense mesh when baked and you should check the bounce settings for _Transmission_, _Glossy_ (and they are also limited by the _Total_ value) and maybe _Transparent_.

Comment: The only thing i messed with in the fluid simulation is the resolution divisions. I changed it from 32 to 160. checked the "mesh" box and assigned the cache folder. bubbles, spray and foam are not active. I don't know why the mesh doesn't hold shaders correctly.

Comment: increasing the max bounces and increasing the glossy, transmission and transparent has very little effect on the imported mesh.

Answer (score 1):

Ok! So I figured it out! It was simply the mesh. I just applied a simple remesh to the object and it worked like a charm!

Comment: Great you could get it to work. I just wanted to comment above, without the file I could ask a lot more questions and it would all be wild speculation. For example there could be issues with the mesh that are not visible in the screenshot. Inverted normals, duplicate faces or vertices and more... _Remesh_ does solve some of these issues, but in case of inverted normals it shouldn't be necessary, there are other ways to "repair" the mesh.

Comment: Thank you! Yeah I didn't really good a good look at the mesh, but when I zoomed in, I could see all the nasty imperfections mataflow gives you after the bake. Which is unfortunate if you're planning on using multiple objects straight from the bake. Luckily, I'll only be needing one. Thank you for the advice!